# how i can make a vhdl function which makes my way a lot shorter

Tags: function, vhdl

I'm new in VHDL and just learning . trying to make a function for bcd to 7segment code so I can call it further. so i made a function named bcd_to_ssd. so it can convert temp1 or temp2 integer values to 7 bit vector in order to connect to 7 segment (abcdefg) bits.

i tried many ways , changed a lot but confused.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
----------------------------------
entity SEVENSEGMENT is
port(clk,reset : IN STD_LOGIC;
digit1,digit2 : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 DOWNTO 0));
end SEVENSEGMENT;

architecture Behavioral of SEVENSEGMENT is
signal tempx : integer;
-----------------------------
function bcd_to_ssd(signal s : INTEGER range 0 to 10 ) return std_logic_vector is
variable d : std_logic_vector (6 DOWNTO 0);
begin

if  s= 0 then d :=  "1111110";
elsif  s= 1 then d := "0110000";
elsif s= 2 then d := "1101101";
elsif s=3 then d := "1111001";
elsif s=4 then d := "0110011";
elsif s=5 then d := "1011011";
elsif s=6 then d := "1011111";
elsif s=7 then d := "1110000";
elsif s=8 then d := "1111111";
elsif s=9 then d := "1111011";
end if;
return d;
end bcd_to_ssd;
---------------------------
begin
Process(clk,reset)
variable temp1,temp2 : integer range 0 to 10;
begin
---------------------
if reset = '1' then
temp1 := 0;
temp2 := 0;
elsif rising_edge(clk) then
temp1 := temp1 + 1;
if temp1 = 10 then
temp1 :=0;
temp2 := temp2 +1;
if(temp2 = 10) then
temp2 := 0;
end if;
end if;
end if;
tempx <= temp1;
-------------------
end process;
digit1 <= bcd_to_ssd(tempx);
end Behavioral;
```

the error is:
Line 51: Direction/bounds for signal formal s must match with that of actual type for subprogram bcd_to_ssd

the original code i'm trying to make a function for it , is below:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity SEVENSEGMENT is
port(clk,reset : IN STD_LOGIC;
digit1,digit2 : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 DOWNTO 0));
end SEVENSEGMENT;

architecture Behavioral of SEVENSEGMENT is

begin
Process(clk,reset)
variable temp1,temp2 : integer range 0 to 10;
begin
---------------------
if reset = '1' then
temp1 := 0;
temp2 := 0;
elsif rising_edge(clk) then
temp1 := temp1 + 1;
if temp1 = 10 then
temp1 :=0;
temp2 := temp2 +1;
if(temp2 = 10) then
temp2 := 0;
end if;
end if;
end if;
-------------------
case temp1 is 
when 0 => digit1 <= "1111110";
when 1 => digit1 <= "0110000";
when 2 => digit1 <= "1101101";
when 3 => digit1 <= "1111001";
when 4 => digit1 <= "0110011";
when 5 => digit1 <= "1011011";
when 6 => digit1 <= "1011111";
when 7 => digit1 <= "1110000";
when 8 => digit1 <= "1111111";
when 9 => digit1 <= "1111011";
when OTHERS => NULL;
end case;
case temp2 is
when 0 => digit2 <= "1111110";
when 1 => digit2 <= "0110000";
when 2 => digit2 <= "1101101";
when 3 => digit2 <= "1111001";
when 4 => digit2 <= "0110011";
when 5 => digit2 <= "1011011";
when 6 => digit2 <= "1011111";
when 7 => digit2 <= "1110000";
when 8 => digit2 <= "1111111";
when 9 => digit2 <= "1111011";
when OTHERS => NULL;
end case;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Your `tempx` signal is an unbounded integer, but your `bcd_to_ssd` function expects a bounded integer of `range 0 to 10`.

Comment: Put those values in a constant array, indexed by `d`, and the function will get even shorter. (You'll also find out about the other range bug at compile time!)

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-1993 2.1.1.2 Signal parameters "If an actual signal is associated with a signal parameter of any mode, and if the type of the formal is a scalar type, then it is an error if the bounds and direction of the subtype denoted by the subtype indication of the formal are not identical to the bounds and direction of the subtype denoted by the subtype indication of the actual. "

Comment: -2008 4.2.2.3 Signal parameters "If an actual signal is associated with a signal parameter of mode in or inout, and if the type of the formal is a scalar type, then it is an error if the subtype of the actual is not compatible with the subtype of the formal. Similarly, if an actual signal is associated with a signal parameter of mode out or inout, and if the type of the actual is a scalar type, then it is an error if the subtype of the formal is not compatible with the subtype of the actual."

Comment: -2008 5.2 Scalar types, 5.2.1 General "If a range constraint is used in a subtype indication, the type of the expressions (likewise, of the bounds of a range attribute) shall be the same as the base type of the type mark of the subtype indication. A range constraint is *compatible* with a subtype if each bound of the range belongs to the subtype or if the range constraint defines a null range. Otherwise, the range constraint is not compatible with the subtype. A subtype S1 is *compatible* with a subtype S2 if the range constraint associated with S1 is compatible with S2."

Answer (score 0):

THE answer is this:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
------Package Decleration-----------
package sevensegmentdisplay is
function bcd_to_ssd(signal s : INTEGER ) return std_logic_vector;
end sevensegmentdisplay;
---------Package Body----------------
package body sevensegmentdisplay is
-----------Function-----------------
function bcd_to_ssd(signal s : INTEGER ) return std_logic_vector is
variable d : std_logic_vector (6 DOWNTO 0);
begin

case s is
when 1 =>   d :=  "0110000"; 
when 2 =>   d :=    "1101101"; 
when 3 =>   d :=    "1111001"; 
when 4 =>   d :=    "0110011"; 
when 5 =>   d :=    "1011011"; 
when 6 =>   d :=    "1011111"; 
when 7 =>   d :=    "1110000"; 
when 8 =>   d :=    "1111111"; 
when 9 =>   d :=    "1111011"; 
when OTHERS => NULL;
end case;
return d;
----------------------------------------
end bcd_to_ssd;
end sevensegmentdisplay;
```

Comment: The answer should say why the answer is this.